# Setting a loop in a function to a different thread python

Tags: python

if I have a loop that is sending  a large file to a server and I still want to send information via the same function and socket to the server without interrupting the file send how would I set the loop to run on a different thread or process

```
 def sendtoserver():

 # send a string here without interrupting 

 while not flsize == 0:  # while loop multithread


                            with open(fp, "rb") as f:
                                for _ in progress:
                                    # read the bytes from the file
                                    bytes_read = f.read(flsize)   
                                    bytes_read_small = f.read(flsize)

                                    if not bytes_read:
                                        # file transmitting is done
                                        break

                                    self.s.sendall(bytes_read)

                                    # update the progress bar
                                    progress.update(len(bytes_read))

                                    global file_sent
                                    file_sent = 1
                                    flsize = 1
                                    self.s.shutdown()
                                    self.s.close()
```

Comment: I'd recommend [asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html)

Comment: You'd have to implement some sort of multiplexing within that socket if you want to mix other messages than that file data.